# Do I have to use Windows 8 in order to develop for Windows Store?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8

I really want to rollback W8 but I'd like to have an option to develop for Windows Store (for example I might buy Windows Surface and use it as the testing environment but keep dev on W7).. Is it possible?

When I say an app I mean C# / XAML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Develop Windows Store apps using Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx), you cannot do this.

> Windows Store app development in Visual Studio is supported only on
>   Windows 8. Windows 7 is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Although Windows store app development only supported in Windows 8 but you can always install Windows 8 in VM like Virtual Box to get the job done. Also you can install Windows 8 to a `VHD` so you don't have to partition your hard drive. [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx) are the instructions on that.

Comment: While the VM is a potential solution, I doubt it will be viable for someone using DirectX in a Windows Store App.

Comment: @JustinSkiles  Installing Windows 8 on VHD works perfectly fine and you can develop without any hiccup at all. I have been using it for over a month now and have developed 2 applications.

Comment: Mayank, have you used Direct3D from a VM player with success? I have heard of rendering issues.

Comment: @JustinSkiles you don't need to run VHD in VM player, you can mount the VHD as a local partition and install Windows 8 to it. See the instructions link.

Comment: Mayank, I'm addressing the portion of your answer that suggests using a VM player.

Comment: @JustinSkiles you might be right about that, I haven't done much development in VM player myself, so I can't say specifically that Direct3D will work fine or not but it does work fine under VHD.

Comment: my question was about xaml apps not directx / c++ apps.. so his answer is fine

Comment: XAML is interoperable with DirectX, so I was just trying to cover all the bases. But I see that you specified C#.

Comment: Nothing wrong with covering all the bases. :)